# MP3 player no longer syncs after installing Sixaxis drivers

Tags: usb, drivers, mp3-player, game-controller

I recently installed [third-party drivers](http://boardsus.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3-General/Ever-want-to-use-your-Sixaxis-on-your-PC/m-p/28520596) for the (Sony) PS3 controller on my friend's PC (Windows XP). I found out a few days later that his MP3 player (also Sony) is no longer recognized by Windows. He gets the "connect device" sound, and about 250ms later, the "disconnect device" sound.

I figured the controller driver took over the Walkman's device ID, so I went through the registry and `C:\Windows\inf` removing all references to Sony's VID (`054C`), but I haven't had any luck.

What would you do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'd try to reinstall the mp3 player drivers.

If thatd doens't work I'd then uninstall the 3rd party drivers.

If you can't uninstall then (if you have one) use a restore point from before you installed the drivers.

Assuming you get the mp3 player working again try reinstalling the 3rd party drivers and pay attention to all the prompts. I don't know but it could be that there's a setting you need to change.

If that doesn't work, then you might just have incompatible drivers. Have you checked the 3rd party's site for known problems?